# How do I resolve no module named win32.com

Tags: python

on trying to install
"pip install pywin32"
it results to

```
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\pankaj\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-
32\lib\site-packages (227)
```

on executing the program it shows

```
from win32.com.client import Dispatch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.com'
```

Code I am executing is

```
from win32.com.client import Dispatch
shout = Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speak.speak("Hey ,, How are you")
```

Comment: Are you using pyttsx?

Comment: @ROG_SHAKHYAR Yes

Comment: Hey I recieved the same problem using pip install, as you have closed this question so I was unable to answer, but you don't to install any other stuff with pip. The new pyttsx3 has removed some features. I asked the same problem on stackoverflow few months ago, you need to uninstall pyttsx by `pip uninstall pyttsx3` and use this `python -m pip install pyttsx3==2.71`. You just need the previous version of pyttsx3, not the latest one, and this will solve your problem, I am not sure if the answer given below will solve your problem or not.

Comment: @PankajPandey based on the comments and the answer I've reopened this question.  If the proposed duplicate actually solved your problem you can @ me here to close it again.  Otherwise you can engage with the commenters and answerers until your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

There is no module called `win32.com`. Change `from win32.com.client import Dispatch` to `from win32com.client import Dispatch`.